# Pseudo Element 100% width is not taking container size

Tags: html, css, pseudo-element

I'm using a pseudo element (before) to put a `border` on top of a container inside a two column layout. I want the `border` on top of just one container.

Shouldn't the `width` of the pseudo element (being set to 100%) make it the `width` of the container it's inside?

```css
#singleWrapper {
  margin: auto;
  max-width: 1100px;

}
.single #singleWrapper {
  margin: auto;
  max-width: 1100px;
  /*box-shadow: inset 0 650px rgba(0,0,0,0.30);*/
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}
#leftColumn .content-area {
  padding-right: 310px;
  width: 100%;
}
.articleWrapper:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background: #009cff;
  background: linear-gradient(to right, #1d0027, #935cd2, #1d0027);
  height: 2px;
  width: 100%;
}
#leftColumn .content-area #main {
  background: #000;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.30);
  padding-left: 20px;
  padding-right: 20px;
}
#singleWrapper .contentHolder {
  margin-right: -310px;
  width: 100%;
  float: left;
  position: relative;
}
#rightColumn {
  float: right;
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  width: 290px;
}
#leftColumn,
#rightColumn {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
  margin-top: 1.1em;
}
```

```html
<div id="singleWrapper">
  <div id="leftColumn" class="contentHolder">
    <div id="primary" class="content-area">
      <main id="main" class="site-main" role="main">
        <div class="articleWrapper">
          <h1>Title</h1>
          <div class="articleBody">
            Article Body
          </div>
        </div>
      </main>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="rightColumn">
    Side Bar Area
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

the problem is you are using `position:absolute`

From [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position)

> **Absolute positioning**
>
> Elements that are positioned relatively are still considered to be in
>   the normal flow of elements in the document. In contrast, an element
>   that is positioned absolutely is taken out of the flow and thus takes
>   up no space when placing other elements. The absolutely positioned
>   element is positioned relative to nearest positioned ancestor. If a
>   positioned ancestor doesn't exist, the initial container is used

A fix is to add this to your CSS:

```css
.articleWrapper {
  position:relative;
}
```

and change `top:0;` in `.articleWrapper:before`  to any negative value you like best.

here is a snippet

```css
#singleWrapper {
  margin: auto;
  max-width: 1100px;
}
.single #singleWrapper {
  margin: auto;
  max-width: 1100px;
  /*box-shadow: inset 0 650px rgba(0,0,0,0.30);*/
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}
#leftColumn .content-area {
  padding-right: 310px;
  width: 100%;
}
.articleWrapper {
  position:relative;
}
.articleWrapper:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: -30%;
  left: 0;
  background: #009cff;
  background: linear-gradient(to right, #1d0027, #935cd2, #1d0027);
  height: 2px;
  width: 100%;
}
#leftColumn .content-area #main {
  background: #000;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.30);
  padding-left: 20px;
  padding-right: 20px;
}
#singleWrapper .contentHolder {
  margin-right: -310px;
  width: 100%;
  float: left;
  position: relative;
}
#rightColumn {
  float: right;
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  width: 290px;
}
#leftColumn,
#rightColumn {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
  margin-top: 1.1em;
}
```

```html
<div id="singleWrapper">
  <div id="leftColumn" class="contentHolder">
    <div id="primary" class="content-area">
      <main id="main" class="site-main" role="main">
        <div class="articleWrapper">
          <h1>Title</h1>
          <div class="articleBody">
            Article Body
          </div>
        </div>
      </main>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="rightColumn">
    Side Bar Area
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This actually lead me to something that I THINK fixed it. I didn't want to change the width percentage, because it doesn't stay the proper width as the site re-sizes.

I place `position: relative;` on the #leftColumn .content-area #main tag. I'm still new to absolute positioning. But I think that fixes it.